# Working out how many clients can connect to some tcp server code I am using

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

Updates

It seems the tcp server can handle file descriptors up to 512. Since the first client to connect gets file descriptor 4 the maximum number of clients that can connect is 509 (I can do io between the server and client even for the 509th file descriptor). I am not quite sure where that 512 limit is coming from though? Even if one limits the number of clients below 509, if more than 509 clients connect at the same time, not all of them will be able to get a message that there are too many clients connected to the server unfortunately.

I still have the problem that when I have `MAX_CONNECTIONS = 500` and `CLIENTS_TO_DISCONNECT = 500` (or `CLIENTS_TO_DISCONNECT = 400`) then the `test.cc` program does not terminate and a bunch of telnet processes need to be killed manually. Has anyone run the code on their own machine? If they have, it would be useful to know either way whether people are getting the same problem.

The examples I can find using epoll instead seem quite a lot more difficult to me. That's probably a necessity, but does anyone know of any reasonably simple multi client tcp servers using epoll?

Thankyou to those who have taken the time to read this post, especially those who have responded.

---

Updates 2

I was wrong, the server can handle file descriptors larger than 512. If I start the server then run two copies of `test.cc` with `MAX_CONNECTIONS = 400` then the server has 800 clients connected to it. The server can only handle file descriptors up to 1023 though so can have 1020 clients connected simultaneously.

This means the limit of 509 connections I was hitting before is a limitation of the client `test.cc`, which is quite strange because I would have expected the limit there to be 512, I'm guessing that somehow `client.cc` is also using numbers similar to the file descriptors on the server and hitting a similar wall. I have tried using more than 512 redi::pstream variables for just running "echo 'hello'" and that doesn't seem to have any problems, so I am not sure where the limitation is coming from.

I am also still having trouble getting redi::pstream to close on clients connected after the 419th. This happens both with one instance of `test.cc` and with multiply instances of `test.cc` running.

I have also managed to make some corrections to another multi client tcp server code that uses poll instead of select (see [here](https://pastebin.com/QjgNzvy1) for code). Interestingly it has exactly the same problems (one instance of `test.cc` running can connect a maximum of 509 clients, the server can have a maximum of 1020 clients, and I have trouble getting redi::pstream to close on clients connected after the 419th). I think that suggests the problem with a maximum of 509 clients connecting using one instance of `test.cc` lies in the code for `test.cc` and not the server code, and probably also for the trouble with getting redi::pstream to close on clients connected after the 419th.

---

Updates 3

The second tcp server takes over twice as long as the first with sending and receiving messages back and forth with clients, so I will be using the original code I found (though may also see if I can find an epoll solution that can handle more than 1020 clients connected).

If you get rid of the statements to close pstreams (`redi::pstream`) then the test program seems to end properly (and the clients still disconnect before the test program terminates). However if I let too much input build up on a `redi::pstream` without reading it, the test program fails to terminate.

I also tried [libexecstream](http://libexecstream.sourceforge.net/) instead of pstream. libexecstream breaks when I try to open more than 337 streams. So I can only connect up to 337 clients to the server using libexecstream using one program. However if I run the same program multiple times it can connect more clients to the server.

With pstreams I have the problem that clients connected after 419 doesn't disconnect and close properly, the program stalls. I do not have this problem with libexecstreams, the processes/streams close properly. When I connect say 300 clients using libexecstreams. I can connect another 400 clients using pstream however run in to problems again with closing the pstream for clients connected after 420 to the server. Though this can be fixed with pstreams as suggested above by just not calling close on the pstream.

You also have that input to the server from the clients gets 'grouped', ie. if more than one message arriving before select/poll picks up that messages have arrived then read/recv will read them all in to the buffer array provided. If the combined message is too long for the buffer then the message at the end of the buffer can be 'cut in half', and not easily put back together. I'd suggest this is a pretty big problem if you can't have the buffer size long enough to handle all grouped messages that will arrive within a certain time period. Fortunately there does not seem to be any major change in run time with io when I use a really large buffer size.

One thing to watch out for however is if the buffer size is above 3000. Somewhere above that value you can no longer treat a char array like a string, outputting it and setting it equal to a string does not work. You have to iterate through the char array and individually add the characters to the string. (Note you do not need to do this when sending the data back to the client, but you do need to do it if you want a string version of the buffer char array containing the input from the client).

---

Sorry for the long post, but this has me stumped. I am open to using other code for the tcp server if people know of anything that can handle more clients without getting buggy (though the buggyness here is probably my fault, and I need to be able to put a timeout on when it checks for input from the clients), and if anyone repeats the bugs I am mentioning in this post please do post to say you are experiencing them too, that is helpful even if you cannot work out why the bugs are occurring.

I am trying to learn how to set up a multi client tcp server however I am having trouble when I try to test how many users can connect to the tcp server code that I am using.

The tcp server code that I'm using is below and is a slightly modified version of the tcp server code available [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-cc-handling-multiple-clients-on-server-without-multi-threading/).

Note: modifications are outputting FD_SETSIZE on line 36 (which is 1024 on my machine), changing max_clients to 1500, keeping track of how many clients are connected (`no_clients_connected`), closing connection for new clients when max_clients are already connected and outputting the number of connected clients both when there is a new connection and when a client disconnects.

You can compile the tcp server code (when called `server.cc`) using:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -o server.o server.cc
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic server.cc  -o server
```

Note: Does anyone know what to do about the warning on line 34 about a deprecated conversion from `string` constant to `char*`? (Lightness Races in Orbit has pointed out how to fix this).

If you compile and run the tcp server code, you should be able to connect to it by running `telnet localhost 8888` from a terminal window. To quit, enter `ctrl+]` and then `quit` at the telnet prompt.

```
//Example code: A simple server side code, which echos back the received message.
//Handle multiple socket connections with select and fd_set on Linux
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   //strlen
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>   //close
#include <arpa/inet.h>    //close
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/time.h> //FD_SET, FD_ISSET, FD_ZERO macros

#define TRUE   1
#define FALSE  0
#define PORT 8888

int main()
{
    int no_clients_connected = 0;
    int opt = TRUE;
    int master_socket , addrlen , new_socket , client_socket[1500] ,
          max_clients = 1500 , activity, i , valread , sd;
    int max_sd;
    struct sockaddr_in address;

    char buffer[1025];  //data buffer of 1K

    //set of socket descriptors
    fd_set readfds;

    //a message
    const char *message = "ECHO Daemon v1.0 \r\n";

    std::cout << "FD_SETSIZE " << FD_SETSIZE << std::endl;

    //initialise all client_socket[] to 0 so not checked
    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
    {
        client_socket[i] = 0;
    }

    //create a master socket
    if( (master_socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //set master socket to allow multiple connections ,
    //this is just a good habit, it will work without this
    if( setsockopt(master_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt,
          sizeof(opt)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //type of socket created
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    //bind the socket to localhost port 8888
    if (bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Listener on port %d \n", PORT);

    //try to specify maximum of 3 pending connections for the master socket
    if (listen(master_socket, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //accept the incoming connection
    addrlen = sizeof(address);
    puts("Waiting for connections ...");

    while(TRUE)
    {
        //clear the socket set
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);

        //add master socket to set
        FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);
        max_sd = master_socket;

        //add child sockets to set
        for ( i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++)
        {
            //socket descriptor
            sd = client_socket[i];

            //if valid socket descriptor then add to read list
            if(sd > 0)
                FD_SET( sd , &readfds);

            //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function
            if(sd > max_sd)
                max_sd = sd;
        }

        //wait for an activity on one of the sockets , timeout is NULL ,
        //so wait indefinitely
        activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);

        if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR))
        {
            printf("select error");
        }

        //If something happened on the master socket ,
        //then its an incoming connection
        if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds))
        {
            if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket,
                    (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
            {
                perror("accept");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands
            printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d\n" , new_socket , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));

            if(no_clients_connected >= max_clients)
            {
                close(new_socket);
                std::cout << "kicked them because too many clients connected" << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                no_clients_connected++;

                //send new connection greeting message
                if( (size_t) send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0) != strlen(message) )
                {
                    perror("send");
                }

                puts("Welcome message sent successfully");

                //add new socket to array of sockets
                for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
                {
                    //if position is empty
                    if( client_socket[i] == 0 )
                    {
                        client_socket[i] = new_socket;
                        printf("Adding to list of sockets as %d\n" , i);

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            std::cout << "number of clients connected is " << no_clients_connected << std::endl;
        }

        //else its some IO operation on some other socket
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
        {
            sd = client_socket[i];

            if (FD_ISSET( sd , &readfds))
            {
                //Check if it was for closing , and also read the
                //incoming message
                if ((valread = read( sd , buffer, 1024)) == 0)
                {
                    //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print
                    getpeername(sd , (struct sockaddr*)&address , \
                        (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
                    printf("Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d \n" ,
                          inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));

                    no_clients_connected--;
                    std::cout << "number of clients connected is " << no_clients_connected << std::endl;

                    //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse
                    close( sd );
                    client_socket[i] = 0;
                }

                //Echo back the message that came in
                else
                {
                    //set the string terminating NULL byte on the end
                    //of the data read
                    send(sd, buffer, valread, 0);
                    //buffer[valread] = '\0';
                    //send(sd , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code that I'm using to test the number of clients I can connect is below and uses [pstreams](http://pstreams.sourceforge.net/). On Ubuntu you can get pstreams with `sudo apt-get install libpstreams-dev`, or you can download it [here](http://pstreams.sourceforge.net/#download).

You can compile the code below (when called `test.cc`) using:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -c test.cc -o test.o
g++ -o test test.o -pthread
```

If you run the test code with the server already running, it should make MAX_CONNECTIONS=400 connections to the server. If you go back and check where the server is running, it should now have 400 clients connected. If you then go back to where the test code is running and input a string (it reads a whole line), it should go through and disconnect CLIENTS_TO_DISCONNECT=400 clients and (on my machine) the program ends no problems.

On my machine (2012 11" macbook air running ubuntu), if I change CLIENTS_TO_DISCONNECT to 350 and do the same thing again, the 400 clients connect to the server fine, and (after I input a line) the 350 clients disconnect fine and I get a whole bunch of "Connection closed by foreign host" strings outputted from the clients I didn't disconnect though the test program still exits at the end no problem.

If I change MAX_CONNECTIONS to 500 and CLIENTS_TO_DISCONNECT to 400. 500 clients connect to the server, and when I enter a string for 400 clients to disconnect 400 clients indeed disconnect but the test program does not end and not many of the remaining connections are closed by the foreign host, so the server still thinks it has a bunch of clients connected and the test program needs to be forcefully ended (sometimes leaving telnet processes behind that need to be killed manually as well).

If I change MAX_CONNECTIONS to 550 then I can't even get 550 clients connected to the server. However on [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) page under the BUGS section it says:

> POSIX allows an implementation to define an upper limit, advertised via the constant FD_SETSIZE, on the range of file descriptors that can be specified in a file descriptor set.  The Linux kernel imposes no fixed limit, but the glibc implementation makes fd_set a fixed-size type, with FD_SETSIZE defined as 1024, and the FD_*() macros operating according to that limit.  To monitor file descriptors greater than 1023, use poll(2) instead.

So I was expecting to be able to have at least 1024 clients using select() and possibly more if I switched to using poll(2) instead? Though neither select or poll have anything to do with clients actually connecting to the server, they are to to do with monitoring activity on the file descriptors for the connected clients. (it was pointed out by  Lightness Races in Orbit that the previous sentence is incorrect as select is used to monitor incoming connections).

If anyone can work out why any of the strange behaviour is happening it would be incredibly helpful and appreciated.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <pstreams/pstream.h>

const char ESCAPE_CHAR = 0x1d; //this is 'ctrl+]'
const int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 400;
const int CLIENTS_TO_DISCONNECT = 400;

int main()
{
    redi::pstream servers[MAX_CONNECTIONS];

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
        servers[i].open("telnet localhost 8888");

    std::cout << "'connected'" << std::endl;

    std::string s;
    getline(std::cin, s);

    for(int i=0; i<CLIENTS_TO_DISCONNECT; i++)
    {
        //std::cout << i << std::endl;
        servers[i] << ESCAPE_CHAR << " quit" << std::endl;

        servers[i].close();
    }

    std::cout << "made it to here" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `const char* ptr = "literal";` The `const` is not optional since C++11. It was exceedingly good practice before that.

Comment: _"Though neither select or poll have anything to do with clients actually connecting to the server, they are to to do with monitoring activity on the file descriptors for the connected clients"_ That includes detecting readiness to accept a connection on the listen socket though so what you say isn't quite true

Comment: Cheers, I have updated the post to use `const char*` on line 34. I also added a `(size_t)` to the comparison on line 141 which was also giving a warning.

Comment: A valid point about select being used to detect readiness to accept a connection on the listen socket. I wonder if that's where my problems are arising. I will have a play (though if someone else manages to find the problem(s) in the meantime that'd be awesome too). I wouldn't be surprised if the problem with connecting 500+ clients is there, though I'm still not sure why it is having trouble disconnecting 500 clients once they're already connected, unless there's something buggy with file descriptors above a certain value.

Comment: Apologies for not answering your question directly, but is there a reason why you want to use raw TCP rather than HTTP? At that point it becomes a solved problem and you can use any one of a number of scalable, high-performance HTTP servers.

Comment: I haven't examined the code (this question is a big job - hopefully someone can help!) but I don't think that part sounds like your problem. Just some unrelated observations is all.

Comment: @ScottLeckie it's for running ai games. The server will accept connections from clients which send io back and forth over the internet (server/engine sends bots the game state, or more likely opponent moves to minimise the amount of text each turn, and bots return their move, why I need to be able to put a timeout on input from bots is so I can kick bots that timeout on a turn rather than have the server stall waiting). I know tcp works fine for that purpose, would http work as well? I've no real experience with it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yep I realised I am being a bit hopeful asking for help on this one, however figured it doesn't hurt to try. Doesn't hurt to have a play myself to see if select (or send) are having trouble with the file descriptors above a certain value, but would also be surprised if that's my problem (maybe not so surprised if it's the problem with failing to connect 550 clients). Thanks a lot for the feedback you have given though!

Comment: No certainly and I hope you get your answer. If I find more time later I may take a little peek. I would recommend trying to narrow it down a little more though if possible

Comment: The trouble with HTTP is its overhead, which you can mitigate a little by keeping connections open, but it still may not be appropriate for the designed task. The equivalent suggestion for your use case is probably something like protobuf. _But_ sometimes it's fun to write your own protocol and parser.

Comment: Run `ulimit -n` in bash to check open file limit.

Comment: `ulimit -n` is 1024.

Comment: I just added some further updates under 'Updates 2' if @MaximEgorushkin sees this..

Answer (score 3):

One error in your code is that when condition `no_clients_connected >= max_clients` is `true` it carries on using that socket after it has been disconnected.

---

Instead of:

```
buffer[valread] = '\0';
send(sd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
```

Do:

```
send(sd, buffer, valread, 0);
```

---

For servers that must handle many clients it is better to use `epoll` notification mechanism. It scales much better than `select` and `poll` (see benchmark section on https://libevent.org/).

Comment: You are right about the error when `no_clients_connected >= max_clients` is `true`, I have fixed the server code for this error. Though this error will not have presented itself with the example problems given in the post.

Comment: I have changed to `send(sd, buffer, valread, 0);`, though this should not make much difference for the major problems present unfortunately.

Comment: I will see if I can get an example using `epoll` working, though it would be nice to nut out what the problems are with this example too.